# A proof that any metric space is topological space and some intuition on it

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, metric-spaces

I would like to show that any metric space is a topological space.

First I recall the definition (using the open set) of a topological space : Let $X$ be a set and $\mathcal{O}\subset\mathcal{P}(X)$. If

- $X$ and $\emptyset$ belongs to $\mathcal{O}$
- $(A_i)_{i\in I}\in\mathcal{O}\implies\cup_{i\in I}A_i\in\mathcal{O}$
- $(A_i)_{i=1}^{n}\in\mathcal{O}\implies\cap_{i=1}^{n}A_i\in\mathcal{O}$

We say that $(X,\mathcal{O})$ is a topological space and the elements of $\mathcal{O}$ are called the open set of $X$, moreover $\mathcal{O}$ is called a topology.

My attempt : Now consider a metric space $(X,d)$ and $\mathcal{O}\in\mathcal{P}(X)$ such that $\mathcal{O}$ will be composed of the open subset $A$ of $X$ which is defined as follows : $A\subset X$ is open $\Longleftrightarrow\forall x_0\in A, \exists\epsilon>0 : N(x_0,\epsilon) = \{x\in X : d(x,x_0)<\epsilon\}\subset A$

- Since $X$ and $\emptyset$ are both open we know that they belongs to $\mathcal{O}$.
- Consider $(A_i)_{i\in I}\in\mathcal{O}$ and $x\in\cup_{i\in I}A_i$. Since the $A_i$'s are open, there exists at least one $\epsilon_k$ such that

$N(x,\epsilon_k)\subset A_k\subset\cup_{i\in I}A_i$ which shows that $\cup_{i\in I}A_i\in\mathcal{O}$.

- Consider $(A_i)_{i=1}^{n}\in\mathcal{O}$ and $x\in\cap_{i=1}^{n}A_i$. This means that for all $i\in\{1,...,n\}$ : $\exists\epsilon_i>0 : N(x,\epsilon_i)\subset A_i $.

Take $\epsilon = min\{ \epsilon_i : 1\leq i\leq n\}$. Thus $N(x,\epsilon)\in\cap_{i=1}^{n}A_i$  which shows that $\cap_{i=1}^{n}A_i\in\mathcal{O}$.

This shows that the definition of the open set introduced in a metric space is such that it satisfies the requirement to allow any metric space to be a topological space.

Is this seems correct ?

Also, if you have some good intuition to share about the topology defined within the open set I would be happy. Given the framework provided by metric space and normed space I have seen that under a given metric, the notion of convergence could be totally different from another one metric. But how this is linked with the notion of topology ? Is this because the notion of open set (at least for metric space) depends on the distance you have chosen ?

Thank you a lot !

Comment: Unions of open sets do not have to be countable.

Comment: @Novice Yes you are totally right thank you.

Comment: Apart from this, your proof is correct. As for your last paragraph: two metrics are said topologically equivalent if they induce the same topology. In that case, the notion of convergence is of course the same. Else, it can (of course) be very different. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics

Comment: Your explanation and this link are very usefull.  Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it seems roughly correct, although it could probably be written a bit more clearly.

Metric spaces are topological spaces, as you have seen. Topological spaces are *not* necessarily metric spaces. In a metric space, open sets are derived from the metric, so of course they depend on the measure of distance chosen. Topological spaces do not necessarily have any notion of distance. I have written answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4596479/topology-and-closeness/4596564#4596564) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4469189/what-is-the-big-picture-of-topology/4469834#4469834) that may help provide some intuition about what topology is, at least in an elementary sense.

Comment: These answers are definitively interesting. Thank you !